# Trouble with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble with my regular expression.
I work with a french site and I need use Regex in order to have online letters (some with accents.) in one of my fields.

This is what I did.

```
if( !mb_eregi("^[a-zéèùêëîïôöçñ\-]+$", str_replace(" ", "", $prenom)) )
```

"test" returns FALSE

but "tést" returns TRUE!

Please help!

if $prenom is set to 'tést', the result is false, but I would expect it to be false. How come?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What is your desired output with certain inputs?

Comment: "tést" should also return FALSE because there are only letters in the word, am I not correct?
Why does it return TRUE?

Comment: Try updating your question with something along the lines of: `if $prenom is set to 'test', the result is false, but I would expect it to be true. How come?`

Comment: `preg_match()` is not deprecated but `eregi()` (whereas `mb_eregi` is not). Possibly your input is not UTF-8 which leads to the unwanted result. Try `!preg_match('~^[a-zéèùêëîïôöçñ\-]+$~i',...`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use preg_match with unicode modifier:

```
if( !preg_match('/^[\p{L}-]+$/u', str_replace(" ", "", $prenom)) )
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I also thought that preg_match was depreceate.

Comment: @elti69: In which way it doesn't work? And where have you seen that preg_replace is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Not far from M42 solution, you can avoid the use of `str_replace` and the negation:

```
if (preg_match('/[^p{L} -]/u', $prenom)) { ... }
```

If you want to only deal with french letters:

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zæœéèêëàâäôöîïùûüçÿ -]/ui', $prenom)) { ... }
```